# Change Picklist Value on Opportunity + Update fields

Tags: trigger, process-builder

I have a custom object - **Object 1** and the **Opportunity** object. There was no relationship between the two objects, so I've created a lookup field **from Object 1 to the Opportunity** , that I am populating through a trigger, in order to update some fields **from the custom object on the Opportunity**, but also **to change a picklist value on the Opportunity**.

The records on the **Object 1** are the **Opportunity Line Items** triggered from another system in Salesforce, so every time a modification happens (e.g price) in the other system, a new record is being created in Salesforce for the same OLI, but with the new value (price). The records share the same "lineitemid" to identity that records relate to the same opportunity line item.

What I am trying to achieve:

- to populate **custom field 1 from Opportunity** with **custom field 1a from Object 1**.
- to populate **custom field 2 from Opportunity** with **custom field 2a from Object 1**.
- to change **picklist value on Opportunity** based on below:

  "**A**" - if the text field contains "a", but it might also contain "b", "c" or "d", but it should definitely contain "a".

For each picklist is a combination of the above.

For one picklist value though:

"**E**" - if the text field contain 2 or more of the "a", "b", "c" "d" combination.

What I have done so far:

1. Create the lookup field between the objects and populate it through trigger
2. Created a process on **Object 1** - **when a record is created or edited**, *with immediate actions:* `custom_field1__c FIELD REFERENCE customfield1a__c`

The process builder is populating **the custom field1 on Opportunity** with **the custom field 1a from Object 1** value, but if I get a new record in Salesforce where c**ustom field 2a is populated on Object 1**, it's deleting the value **in the custom field1 on Opportunity** and it's populating the **custom field2 on Opportunity**.

Essentially, I want the process *to keep the value in custom field 1 on Opportunity* and also add the value of custom field2, when it gets populated on Object 1.

I don't seem to be able to find a solution. Any help with be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you use formula fields instead of populating Opp.CustomField1 with CustomObject.CustomField1a?  If those values aren't supposed to change afterwards, formula fields might work wonders here

Comment: @BrianMiller - Hi,Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried this already, but my formula fields were returning "null". I had a look into why and I assume it's because I have used a before trigger to populate the lookup field, because all the records on the custom object are triggered from another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continue, as I've mentioned before, to be concerned that the data model here doesn't quite make sense. But diving in...

Let's start with the basics. You have two objects, Opportunity and this other object, which I'm going to call Line Item since that is the role that it plays. Your Line Items are associated with an Opportunity, which means that the Line Item object contains a lookup field to the Opportunity record. This is a **one-to-many relationship**: an Opportunity has many Line Items, each Line Item has exactly one Opportunity.

> to populate custom field 1 from Opportunity with custom field 1a from Object 1.
>
> to populate custom field 2 from Opportunity with custom field 2a from Object 1.

These expectations do not fit a one-to-many relationship. Remember, Opportunity is the **one**, Line Item is the **many**. How are you proposing to get the field values from *multiple* Line Item records into a single field on *one* Opportunity?

Classically, this is the use case for a Roll-Up Summary Field, or for one of the products (like [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)) that extends roll-up functionality to situations not supported by the native Roll-Up Summary Field.

The way that you articulate it below

> Essentially, I want the process to keep the value in custom field 1 on Opportunity and also add the value of custom field2, when it gets populated on Object 1.

sounds like what you have is *multiple* fields on the Opportunity, and you want to populate them with fields from the related Line Items in sequence as the Line Items are created.

This does not really make sense to me and it *certainly* won't scale well, but it is *possible*. (What happens when you get to 4 Line Items? Do you need 4 fields? What about 12?)

You'd need to build out your Process to condition its update actions on whether or not the related Opportunity's fields are blank. You'd update Field 1, for example, if it's blank. You'd update Field 2 if field 1 is not blank and Field 2 is blank. You'd update Field 3 (if needed) if Field 1 and 2 are not blank and Field 3 is blank.

This will get messy, fast. I strongly suspect this is either (a) a data model that is mismatched with the problem it is intended to solve or (b) an x-y problem.

#### Edit

Per your comments, what you want is to concatenate the values of a specific field from your Line Items on the parent Opportunity.

You can either build your Process Builder automation to take into account existing values in the field and *concatenate* new values, rather than overwriting the existing value, or use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries to build a Concatenate Distinct rollup to populate the field.

Your formula field is really a completely different problem. You will need to finish a successful solution for summarizing this line-level detail at the Opportunity level before you are able to begin writing a formula field against it.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot.In order to make more sense: We have SF integrated with a booking system and the booking system sends to Salesforce, a new line item - every time it's being created or modified in the other system - containing the new amendment. For one Opportunity in SF, there can be up to 2 Bookings in the other system. For the business requirements, I need to be able to show on the Opportunity Page in SF, the booking numbers from the other system.

Comment: For example.I have Opp 123 in SF and for this Opp I have 2 Bookings in the other system - 456 and 789. When they are coming back to SF, I have 4 different line items having booking number (custom field) = 456 and another 3 different line items having second booking number (custom field) = 789. As there was no relationship between the two objects. I have created the lookup and trigger.

Comment: I have created a PB on the custom object with field reference between the fields, and it does populate me the booking number 1 = 456 on the Opportunity Page, but once I have received the second booking number, it removes the value 456 from the Opportunity Page and it populates me in the correct field on the Opp Page = 789

Comment: I had to use a before trigger to populate the lookup. I assume that's the reason why it returns null?

Comment: Also, the difficult part is to change the pick-list value from the Opportunity, because I can have the same line item send 4 times if any amends are happening in the booking system. They do have a lineitemnumber = 111 they share, but I was hoping to do this in the PB, as I don't think I can use the last "created date" in a before trigger querying that the field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. I will give the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries a try. I will read the considerations and the how to's. I will come back to you. The formula fields were Brian's suggestion to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Hi David, I have successfully installed the package in Sandbox and tested it. I have used Aggregate Operation = First, so it can only look at the first value of each booking number as they will never change and it seems to be working fine. The value is not being overwritten anymore, which it's great. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: I still need to look into changing the pick-list on Opportunity, as I am not sure this tool will work, because I am getting a new line item for each modification to the product in the booking system. There is a unique id that I will need to query to check its related to the same line item. But I don't think I am able to use the most recent "created date" in a before trigger?